# How should I handle a large JSON dataset with Scikit.Learn?

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, dataset, scikit-learn

I began learning myself data analysis and machine learning recently and ran quickly into my first issue.

I have the data from a REST API stored in JSON. My dataset is a folder with near 350.000 text files containing the JSON returned by the Riot API match endpoint (I store League Of Legends games), summing up 11GB of text files uncompressed. File names are the IDs of the matches.

Obviously I cant load all that data into memory (8GB) to analyze it or handle it with Scikit.Learn. And even if I could, parsing is extremely slow (Getting number of soloQ games, average win ratio of champions...). I've been told to store that data in a SQLite database, but I'm not really decided what to do. SQLite should be OK as future analysis will not need all the features, so I could do SELECT easily.

What are the best approach or what should I know before? Is any essential knowledge of data analysis I'm missing?

Comment: Could you provide a clearer problem statement? What have you tried? What works? What doesn't work? What works even if it's not a complete solution? More specifically, why do you think scikit.learn can't be used? How would you use scikit.learn if the dataset was smaller? Maybe show us some code?